# Visual Studio red highlighted code lines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting

I have some line of code highlighted in red, I don't think there is something wrong with them, maybe I accidentally entered a key combination. How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very much like you have turned on the "Highlight Code Coverage" option and have recently ran a test run with coverage enabled.

[image]

To turn it off, open the Code Coverage Results window and click the Code Coverage Coloring button again to toggle it off.

- To toggle displaying which lines have been run, choose <kbd>[image]</kbd> Code Coverage Coloring.

See also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx